# How can I find data in nested objects or arrays in NodeJs with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I want to find user cart item quantity with cart item slug

My mongoose collection is like this

```
"username" :'anything',
"email " : 'something'
"cart":[{"slug":"m-tshirts/blue-tshirt-1","quantity":"5"}]}
```

I tried this code

```
 UserModel.findOne({ username : 'anything' , 'cart.slug' :'m-tshirts/blue-tshirt-1'   
 }).exec((err,data)=>{
        console.log(data.cart);

 })
```

But I don't know how can I access to specific 'item' in cart. It works if I use

```
data.cart[0].quantity;
```

But I didn't know the id of this card object. So how can I access quantity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) into find in this way:

```
db.collection.find({
  username: "anything",
  "cart.slug": "m-tshirts/blue-tshirt-1"
},
{
  cart: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "slug": "m-tshirts/blue-tshirt-1"
    }
  }
})
```

Which returns the array `cart` with elements which matches the condition.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "cart": [
      {
        "quantity": "5",
        "slug": "m-tshirts/blue-tshirt-1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2D-tGjsVYEQ)

Another option is to use the `aggregation` in this way:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$cart"
},
{
  $match: {
    username: "anything",
    "cart.slug": "m-tshirts/blue-tshirt-1"
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    _id: 0,
    "cart": 1
  }
})
```

Which returns only the object into `cart` that matches the condition:

```
[
  {
    "cart": {
      "quantity": "5",
      "slug": "m-tshirts/blue-tshirt-1"
    }
  }
]
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mVJj-FLuUTF)